# MYSQL Create PROCEDURE (if string contains then reject to add)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a procedure in MySQL to create. This procedure may be used this like:

```
IF USERNAME CONTAINS "XXX" THEN REJECT ADD TO THE DATABASE
```

Is it possible to do such a procedure?

Comment: I think you are trying to create the proc as `IF USERNAME CONTAINS "XXX" THEN REJECT ELSE ADD TO THE DATABASE'? Please confirm.

Comment: yes  that's what i mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SET @a = (SELECT INSTR(your_col,"xxx")); 
  IF(@a==0) THEN
  {here your INSERT command}
  END IF;
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative which I prefer (because you do not have to do a SELECT nor set an additional variable is to use the `LOCATE()` function.

```
IF (LOCATE(@username,'xxx') > 0) THEN
{reject this username as xxx was found}
END IF;
```